# Unable to create more than one package in src folder

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm following this tutorial https://danielniko.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/simple-crud-using-jsp-servlet-and-mysql/ and I'm slightly stuck. I would like to create the 4 packages in the src folder, but Eclipse will only allow me to create one.

I create the first one, It adds it to the src folder:

[image: It adds it to the src folder]

I create the next package, It adds it outside of the src folder:

[image: It adds it outside of the src folder]

I move it into the src folder, It creates a copy and put it in libraries:

[image: It creates a copy and put it in libraries]

Any idea what I can do to stop this happening? I want to put 4 packages in the src folder as per the tutorial but I don't know what is happening. I've been using Eclipse for a while and this has never happened.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, it does put them in the src folder, but I have to refresh the project for it to do so.